# Fully configured ruby development environment with vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I would like to have a fully configured ruby unix development environment using Vagrant configuration and provisioning.  Ideally it would refer to a simple base box (e.g., precise32) and build the environment up through provisioning in such a way thait it will easily be repeatable for other team members, can be posted to github, and can be upgraded as new versions of the different technologies are available by just changing the provisioning.  I have not found any full examples of this searching the web although [Rails Dev Box][1] has some useful ideas.  Most of the dev environment examples (like Rails Dev Box) do not set up the guest dev environment because they assume dev will be done on the host using a shared file strategy - or if they do the configuration by hand and then save the box rather than provisioning it.

This also needs to work both in behind a proxy as well as with no proxy.

Here are the steps I am thinking will be required:

On the host:

- install virtualbox, vagrant, vagrant proxyconf

On the guest, via Vagrantfile/provisioning:

- use a base unix box (e.g., precise32)
- optionally set proxy variables (if proxyconf plugin is installed and http_proxy env var is set)
- provision everything else (puppet, chef, or shell script)

  - install various unix tools (apt-get install git, etc.expo ...)
  - set up bash environment
  - set up vim environment (pathogen plugin, ruby plugins, etc.)
  - install rvm
  - install ruby 1.9, 2.0, JRuby, Rubinius
  - installs and configures tmux

Ideally I could push this into github, it could be cloned, then `cd` to new directoy, and `vagrant up` to have a fully configured dev environment ...

Does anyone have any examples of doing this?

Comment: There is a service out there, [Rove][http://rove.io], that looks very promising.  You select features, most of what I have above, and it will generate a Vagrantfile and a Cheffile for you which you copy to your target directory.  To use the Cheffile you must have the librarian-chef gem installed and then you run librarian-chef in that directory to get the recipes you need copied into the cookbook subdirectory.  Then, in concept, you can run `vagrant up` and immediately get a vm provisioned and running.  So far unfortunately I have been unsuccessful at this on Windows (errors provisioning).

Comment: Another similar service to Rove out there (based on Puppet rather than Chef) is [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/), "A simple GUI to set up virtual machines for Web development." It looks great but does not yet seem to support Ruby (currently only PHP and HHVM).

Comment: Another development environment creator that looks promising is [Fig][http://www.fig.sh/rails.html] which leverages Docker to create teh dev environment.  Fig was acquired by Docker so good things may happen there in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

My preference for doing a task like this would be to use puppet as the provisioning step in your Vagrantfile.

With something like this, you can always get something thrown together quick and dirty by just doing all the steps in a shell provisioner... but I prefer the puppet and modules approach as I've found it easier to maintain, extend and to share with the team.

I've experimented with a couple of different ways of doing the provisioning with Ruby and rvm as you mentioned;

1. Theres the rvm puppet module by [maestrodev](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/rvm) which allows you to configure many of rvms core features: ruby versions, gemsets, gems and rvm wrappers.  Typically to manage which puppet modules are included with a project I use the  librarian-puppet gem which allows you to use a Puppetfile to specify the module and the version you require, much like bundler.  This handles dependencies such as the stdlib and concat modules.  This scenario requires external internet access to have been configured before provisioning so as to be able to download ruby and rubygems.
2. Offline installation of rvm - I made the relevant files (rvm itself, ruby and rubygems)  accessible to the vagrant machine using a shared folder and turned the [offline rvm instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/offline) into a (not very good) puppet module and used that.  One particular gotcha to pay attention to here is the naming of the ruby source that gets installed; the extension has to be .tar.bz2, its described in the list.

Additionally for your other provisioning steps you can build up puppet modules yourself for your additional requirements: vim / tmux etc and keep this versioned separately in git. You can get pretty far with modules with just the ['puppet trifecta'](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet_core_types_cheatsheet.pdf):

```
class vim {
  package { 'vim':
    ensure => installed,
  }
  file { '.vimrc':
    ensure => file,
    ...
  }
}
```

Additionally check out [the puppet forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com) for modules which might have already been written to do what you want.

So heres an example of what you could check in:

```
/ Puppetfile
/ README.md
/ Vagrantfile
/ puppet 
  /manifests
    site.pp
```

And the vagrant provisioner would be

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path    = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
  end
end
```

I've used a rake task before to use librarian-puppet to pull in puppet dependencies from git / puppet forge and any additional steps you might need to do before vagranting up. This way the code as configuration is all you check in.

Finally, with puppet you can use the facter and [hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html) tools which are very useful for keeping data out of your modules and worth having a look at as a means of refactoring once you have your initial setup working.

Comment: This looks like just the approach I am looking for, I will try it out as soon as I can ...

Comment: Is puppet better that chef for doing this type of thing?  Or is it a toss up?

Comment: For me, I am more familiar with puppet; I can get going with it faster and so far it has very much fulfilled my needs. I haven't really tried much with chef.   In the configuration management sphere there is also Ansible and Salt, both of which integrate with Vagrant provisioning.  I read this answer recently  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879747/vagrant-provisioning-shell-vs-puppet-vs-chef