# Setting up vagrant with the following configuration

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, chef-infra, vagrant

Upon learning [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/), I am amazed by its functionalities and benefits as a developer, operations manager, and client. I am studying how to create a Vagrant with the following requirements:

- Box: "precise32" <strike>(done)</strike>
- Apache2 <strike>(done)</strike>
- MySQL (error)
- phpMyAdmin (pending)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) (pending)

So far I have this [Vagrantfile](http://pastebin.com/AYMDug1k#) with inline shell scripts for loading the said requirements. Unfortunately I am having problems installing mysql module for it requires a prompt for password input for root user. And possible the same goes for phpMyAdmin.

I have also learned a simpler way (I guess) to configure vagrant via Chef on the VagrantFile. I need some tutorials to follow or a guide to modify my [Vagrantfile](http://pastebin.com/AYMDug1k#) with [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).

---

**Update Log**

- Updated list of requirements (added [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/))

Comment: You don't modify your Vagrantfile with Chef. You configure :chef_solo or :chef_client provisioner in Vagrantfile (similar way you have :shell provisioner configured). Look for opscode Chef cookbooks and Chef docs. http://docs.opscode.com/ and http://community.opscode.com/

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125374/how-do-i-configure-chef-solo-to-install-nginx-on-a-new-vagrant-box/19127033#19127033

Comment: I've seen this post. However, would it matter if I use 'precise32' box? and `apache2` instead of `nginx`. Although `nginx` is considered a lighter alternative to apache, I would still consider using apache. For the MySQL and phpMyAdmin, should I just add a recipe to the said libraries?

Answer (score 1):

In order to install phpmyadmin just put these commands into your cli:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

sudo php5enmod mcrypt

sudo service apache2 restart

In order to install phpmyadmin for vagrant, you have to navigate to the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and put in

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

and restart the apache2 server.

And this is an article on how to install cakephp on a linux distribution:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cakephp-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *Chef Solo* example of one of my Vagrant setups using MySQL. You will need the [MySQL Cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/mysql) in the `chef/cookbooks` directory.

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["chef/cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe "mysql"
    chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"

    chef.json = {
        :mysql => {
            :server_root_password => "root",
            :server_repl_password => "root",
            :server_debian_password => "root"
        }
    }
end
```

Comment: If I am going to add recipe for `apache2` instead of having it installed via bash script, would I still need to do something else prior to added `chef.add_recipe "apache2"` before adding mysql recipe?

Comment: @Dr.Java Sounds about right. I'd use the [apache2](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apache2) cookbook

Comment: Do I need a `Berksfile` running vagrant up an message `The cookbook path '<project_dir>/chef/cookbooks` deosn't exists. Ignoring...` and an error prompts at the end `Chef never successfully completed...`. I've tried to add `chef.add_recipe "apt"` and the same errors is also shown.

Comment: @Dr.Java What on Earth is a *Berksfile*? Did you create a `chef/cookbooks` directory and put the relevant cookbooks in there (mysql, apache2, etc)? If you get stuck, check out this Vagrant LAMP project - https://github.com/r8/vagrant-lamp

Comment: `Berksfile` is the file needed for `Berkshelf` plugin. Have you tried to run the script above? Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: @Dr.Java No idea about that. Never heard of it before and you certainly didn't mention it in your question

Comment: Sorry about that. But can you provided a link for your `Vagrantfile`. I have uninstalled my plugins yet the same error (comment above) is still shown.