# Very simple Vagrant setup with either Chef or Puppet

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, puppet, chef-solo

I'm trying to get a very basic Vagrant setup working that basically does the following:
Creates a new Precise64 VM and installs a list of packages (simple stuff—all I need is git, python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, and postgres). It'd be nice to also have it run a simple shell script, but I don't absolutely need it.

I've been able to get Vagrant to start a Precise64 VM, but figuring out the provisioning with both Puppet and Chef has been difficult. What's the basic syntax for Puppet or Chef (whichever's easier) to install packages (i.e., run `sudo apt-get install`)?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125374/how-do-i-configure-chef-solo-to-install-nginx-on-a-new-vagrant-box/19127033#19127033

Comment: This might be helpful: https://puphpet.com

Answer (score 0):

For puppet (from the puppet [docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html)) you could do something like this for the openssh package on Ubuntu:

```
# /root/examples/ssh.pp
package { 'openssh-server':
  ensure => present,
  before => File['/etc/ssh/sshd_config'],
}
file { '/etc/ssh/sshd_config':
  ensure => file,
  mode   => 600,
  source => '/root/examples/sshd_config',
}
service { 'sshd':
  ensure     => running,
  enable     => true,
  subscribe  => File['/etc/ssh/sshd_config'],
}
```

You can test it with something like this:

```
puppet apply --debug --noop /root/examples/ssh.pp
```