# No resource or method named `template' chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

Actually try to write wirst cookbook with chef-solo and I am look up to cookbook wordpress to initialize my own site.

But for few hours I couldn't find solution for this bug:

```
No resource or method named `template' for `Chef::Recipe "create_configs"'
```

On fragment:

```
template "#{project_config_dir}/database.php" do
  source "database.php.erb"
  mode 0440
  owner "root"
  group node['apache']['group']
  variables(
    'dev' => {
      'type' => app_db_config['type'],
      'hostname' => app_db_config['hostname'],
      'port' => app_db_config['port'],
      'username' => app_db_config['user'],
      'password' => app_db_config['password'],
      'database' => app_db_config['dababase'],
    } 
  )
  action :create
end
```

with Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.11", :bridge => 'en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'

  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/Tom/Documents/vagrant/destination_server/public", "/home/vagrant/public"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    # Don't boot with headless mode
     vb.gui = false

   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
 end

  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "/etc/init.d/networking restart"

  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get update -y"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3 -y"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get install rubygems -y"

  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "cd /home/vagrant && sudo ./postinstall.sh"

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "bazaar"

    chef.json = {
      "mysql" => {
        "server_debian_password" => "root",
        "server_root_password" => "root",
        "server_repl_password" => "root"
      },
      "run_list" =>["recipe[mysql::server]"]  
    }

    chef.add_recipe "site"


  end
end
```

Funny think is that resource "directory" working fine, but the same problem I have with use "execute".

Used cookbook wordpress and added all needed cookbooks and workend fine with this two resources.

I have version 11.10 of chef.
Using Vagrant to create VirtualMachine

Any idea? Need help/clue what to do :/

Comment: I've seen this just recently on a known working recipe.  Re-running chef-client a few minutes later fixed it, so I expect it's a bug in Chef.  )-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what the error is, but your vagrant file appears to be unnecessarily complicated.

I would suggest you use the omnibus plugin to mange the installation of chef and the Berkshelf plugin to manage cookbooks. For an example I suggest:

- [How do I configure Chef Solo to install Nginx on a new Vagrant box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125374/how-do-i-configure-chef-solo-to-install-nginx-on-a-new-vagrant-box/19127033#19127033)

## Suggested edits

### Berksfile

This file is require by [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) and lists your cookbook dependencies. These will be automatically download from the community site. Here I'm assuming that the custom "site" cookbook is located under a *cookbooks* sub-directory:

```
site :opscode

cookbook "apt"
cookbook "bazaar"
cookbook "mysql"
cookbook "site", :path "cookbooks/site"
```

### Vagrantfile

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Box   
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  # Plugins
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  # Network
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.11", :bridge => 'en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'

  # Storage
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/Tom/Documents/vagrant/destination_server/public", "/home/vagrant/public"

  # Virtualbox
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    # Don't boot with headless mode
    vb.gui = false

    # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end

  # Chef solo provisioning
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "bazaar"
    chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
    chef.add_recipe "site"

    chef.json = {
      "mysql" => {
        "server_debian_password" => "root",
        "server_root_password" => "root",
        "server_repl_password" => "root"
      }
    }
  end    
end
```

**Notes:**

- The shell provisioner is replaced by a omnibus variable indicating which version of chef should be installed
- The *add_recipe* methods will construct the run list for you.

Comment: This solved my problem, but i don't know how. A lot problems with install berkshelve on OS Meveric with `gem install berkshelf`. Better start with instalation: `gem install minitar --install-dir ~/.vagrant.d/gems` But now i can go to next work. Thanks

Comment: @thomasso88 Your original issue could have been anything: The version of chef, the version of your cookbooks and Ubuntu Maveric (10.10) is a very old OS.... I'm glad it now works. The Berkshelf and omnibus plugins are very useful when working on vagrant. Your next advanture is the chef-zero plugin :-)

Comment: O`Conno - Yes - anything. For excaple i had the same problem with `execution`, `action :run`. When I added this - problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

While Mark's answer helped you fix your problem, the original issue you ran into where Chef threw the error message -

```
No resource or method named `template' for `Chef::Recipe "create_configs"'
```

is actually caused by the `template` resource containing something that throws a `NoMethodError`.

So:

```
template "#{project_config_dir}/database.php" do
  # some code here
  something_(like_a_node_attribute)_that_raises_no_method_error
end
```

**If I had to guess, I would assume you didn't include the `apache` cookbook in your run-list, since you most likely have all your `app_db_config` attributes set somewhere**.

```
 group node['apache']['group']
  variables(
    'dev' => {
      'type' => app_db_config['type'],
      'hostname' => app_db_config['hostname'],
      'port' => app_db_config['port'],
      'username' => app_db_config['user'],
      'password' => app_db_config['password'],
      'database' => app_db_config['dababase'],
    } 
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I used this [article](http://leopard.in.ua/2013/01/04/chef-solo-getting-started-part-1/) as tutorial. After all I want to create own cookbook. I named it *ruby* and saved in **site_cookbooks**. I added default recipe with simple code:

```
execute "install_ruby_through_rvm" do
   command "rvm install #{default['ruby']['install_version']}"
   action :run
end
```

I have tried the solution that proposed by Mark O'Connor but I get only one result every time:

```
Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/ruby2/recipes/default.rb:

3:  # Recipe:: default
4:  #
5:  # Copyright 2014, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME
6:  #
7:  # All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
8:  #
9:  
10>> execute "install_ruby_through_rvm" do
11:    command "rvm install #{default['ruby']['install_version']}"
12:    action :run
13:  end 14:  


[2014-02-10T21:50:01+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-02-10T21:50:01+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-02-10T21:50:01+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-02-10T21:50:01+00:00] ERROR: No resource or method named `execute' for `Chef::Recipe "default"'
```

I don't understand what's wrong?

**UPDATED**

I'm just a fool:-) The problem was in a hash with attributes! The correct recipe:

```
execute "install_ruby_through_rvm" do
   command "rvm install #{node['ruby']['install_version']}"
   action :run
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you sure get that error if, i.e. you write "mod" instead of "mode" as just happened to me